# Troar nome do download selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou baixando um pdf através da navegação automática pelo site, para isso eu desativei a visualização de pdf do chrome e ativei para baixar o pdf automaticamente, teria como eu mudar o nome desse arquivo em pdf pelo código?
São 64 arquivos, pensei em jogar uma variável sem nada, e dar um nome específico para cada uma das 64, teria como?

Primeiro trecho de Còdigo serve para desativar o visualizador de pdf e fazer download automático e o seugundo é o botão que clico para o download

```
chrome_options = Options()
    download_dir = "C:\scrapy"
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
        "download": {
        "prompt_for_download": False,
        "default_directory"  : download_dir
        }
    })

conta_completa = driver.find_element_by_id('btnVerContaCompleta')
    conta_completa.click()
    sleep(20)
```

Comment: Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Achei que não tinha necessidade de uma parte do código pela explicação, mas coloquei ai

Answer (score 0):

Não, isso não é possível. O que você pode fazer é criar uma pasta temporária, usando `tempfile.mkdtemp()` e passar ela no seu `default_directory`... Assim o navegador vai salvar os arquivos nela. Depois você move o arquivo para outra pasta com o nome que você quiser pelo python usando `shutil.move()`...

Outra coisa que não é possível fazer é saber quando o download terminou. No caso do chrome, com essa dica de pasta separada para o download, você pode fazer isso verificando a existência de arquivos parciais de download na pasta.

```
chrome_options = Options()
download_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
        "download": {
        "prompt_for_download": False,
        "default_directory"  : download_dir
        }
    })
    #...
    conta_completa = driver.find_element_by_id('btnVerContaCompleta')
    conta_completa.click()
    sleep(5)  # espera o download começar
    while glob.iglob(os.path.join(download_dir, '*.crdownload')): 
        sleep(1)  # espera o download terminar
    # pega o 1o pdf que tiver, só terá 1 pois a pasta estava vazia antes:
    arquivo = glob.iglob(os.path.join(download_dir, '*.pdf'))[0] 
    shutil.move(arquivo, r'C:\scrapy\resultado.pdf')
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(download_dir) # remove todos os arquivos temporários
```

Comment: ajuda muito isso, pq criando 64 pastas eu jogo cada uma na pasta correta e nao preciso alterar o nome, apesar de deixar o codigo bem longo, por isso eu pergunto, mesmo depois de alterar a pasta nao tem nenhuma forma de alterar o nome do arquivo?

Comment: O que o Selenium faz é simular a interação do usuário, @guilherme - ele só consegue fazer o clique no link. Você configurou o navegador para não perguntar o nome antes de salvar. O selenium clica, o arquivo é salvo pelo navegador na pasta configurada para downloads.